# MySQL update query is giving an Error:

Tags: mysql

Here is my sql statement:

```
String sql = "update student "
           + " set first_name=?, last_name=?, email=?"
           + " where id=? ";
```

I am using mysqlWorkbench and this is the error i am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?, last_name=?, email=? where id=?' at line 1

Comment: Can you post the *whole* set of statements you are trying to execute?

Comment: From which language are you calling this query?

Comment: Java, I am using DAO to access Database

Comment: My DAO object talk to my database and servlet, it s only when i try to update the information from the browser that i get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because `?` is not a valid character to set. This query is probably a `prepared statement` in the code you've copied this from.

This basically means that the `?` characters get replaced with actual data passed in your code. For example:

```
UPDATE student SET first_name='John', last_name='Doe', email='johndoe@apple.com' WHERE id=12345
```

Simply copying this query and pasting it in MySQL Workbench (or whatever database client) is not going to work.